# How do lawyers find expert witnesses?

Tags: trial, witnesses

When a lawyer needs an expert witness I assume he looks for three things:

1. Unimpeachable credentials
2. Motivation to support his case
3. The ability to favorably impress a jury, via a compelling demeanor and convincing, lucid, and engaging testimony.

For commonly litigated fields like medicine I assume there are directories and services for experts?  But what about less common fields?  Maybe statistics, ballistics, chemistry, applied physics?

Or, looking at this question another way: Suppose I am an expert in a field and I have been told that I have a gift for engaging a lay audience in it.  How might I alert interested lawyers to my willingness to serve as an expert witness?  Is there a competitive market for expert witnessing?

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**:  Yes, there is a competitive market for experts.

**Background**

As an example, firms like [Compass Lexicon](http://www.compasslexecon.com/), [Analysis Group](http://www.analysisgroup.com/), [Cornerstone](https://www.cornerstone.com/), and [Charles River](http://www.charlesriverassociates.com/) all do economic and forensic consulting, which is helpful for antitrust, securities, and corporate cases writ large.  In the U.S. they're frequently brought in by a client's legal team, so the analysis is generally protected by the work-product doctrine in [Fed. Rules of Civ. Pro. 26(b)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_26).  This speaks to #2 above.

Regarding #3 and #1, the firms bring in prominent faculty members or researchers to enhance the credibility of testimony.

If you're an expert in _______, a good starting point might be to get in touch with a few forensic _______ consulting firms.  By nature, they'd have their ear to the rail concerning upcoming litigation.